# Tablespace error upon creating table

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm facing this weird issue.

When I want to create a table, it says Tablespace-xxx exist.
But when I want to remove that Tablespace-xxx, it says it is not exist.

I'm using mysql in google cloud, second generation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting. Please email the name of your project and database instance to cloud-sql@google.com (along with a link to this post) and we can follow up there.

Comment: ,it has been few days since my first email to cloud-sql@google.com, unfortunately, yet to hear from google team. Can you please give some advice?